# Get proc macro caller location in the proc macro

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I have a proc macro that needs to read files relative to the caller location:

```rust
// main_crate/src/lib.rd
use other_crate::my_proc_macro;

my_proc_macro!(file1, file2)
```

This would mean the proc macto needs to read `main_crate/some_dir/file1.txt` and `main_crate/some_dir/file2.txt`. When To do this properly so it can be used as a dependency, I need to know the absolute path to `main_crate` when running `my_proc_macro` to be able to generate constants.

I don't think I can use the `#[track_caller]` attribute because that wouldn't give me an absolute path and would be run after the proc macro has finished. I also can't use `include_str!` because that's expanded after the proc macro is finished. Same issue with `file!`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use environment variables for this. Because the proc macro crate is under the main crate, I'm just using `env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR")` and getting relative paths from that.

If you didn't have the proc macro crate always relative to the crate using it, then I'd recommend using environment variables in the build script for the main crate that the proc macro runs on.